# append integer to an array (using express and pg-promise)

Tags: arrays, postgresql, pg-promise

I am using the [array_append](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html) function from PostgreSQL's docs, and I don't see what I'm doing wrong, yet get the following error:

```
error:  { error: invalid input syntax for integer: "{22}"
```

Here is the query:

```
UPDATE epics 
   SET collection_ids = array_append(collection_ids, '{${id}}') 
WHERE id = ${epicId}
```

Here is the code for the table:

```
CREATE TABLE epics (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  title varchar,
  collection_ids SMALLINT[]
);
```

Comment: The problem was I had the brackets. It works with: '${id}'

Comment: If you are using it via `pg-promise`, your code may be wrong either way. You should include the query-executing part/method.

Comment: According to the documentation, it expects a value. So why quote it to begin with? Shouldn't it just be `array_append(collection_ids, ${id})`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the comment from [@abelisto](https://stackoverflow.com/users/593144/abelisto), this is the best solution:

```
UPDATE epics SET collection_ids = collection_ids || ${id}::SMALLINT
WHERE id = ${epicId}
```

It is more elegant, because it is SQL-native, no type ambiguity, and even supports an array, if it becomes needed (below we presume `${id}` passed in as an array):

```
UPDATE epics SET collection_ids = collection_ids || ${id}::SMALLINT[]
WHERE id = ${epicId}
```

Because in `pg-promise`, an array of `1,2,3` will be automatically formatted as `array[1,2,3]`.

Answer (score -1):

`UPDATE epics SET collection_ids = array_append(collection_ids, '${id}') WHERE id = ${epicId}`

Works.

Comment: Your own answer is again invalid. The server will understand it, by recasting into integer, but there is no reason to wrap it into quotes the way you do. Also, in the future, if you find a solution to your own question, choose to either delete your question or give others time to review and answer. But answering your own question  immediately is generally not a good idea, especially by giving the wrong solution.

Comment: A better solution is `array_append(collection_ids, ${id}::SMALLINT)`. That way there is no ambiguity between what you are passing in and what is really expected. Otherwise, if you pass in a string instead of number, for example, the result will be broken.

Comment: @vitaly-t `collection_ids || ${id}`?

Comment: @Abelisto That seems even better (more elegant), and it supports passing in an array, and not just one value.

Comment: got it thanks! Marked the other answer as the solution!